# Better use "smallint" or "bit"?

Tags: sql, boolean

I've always thought that `bit` was faster than `smallint` in databases like MySQL and MSSQL.

Now a workmate says that `bit` cannot be indexed (I knew it) and so is better use always `smallint` even if the values will always be just `0` and `1`.

I think an index on a `smallint` with only `0` and `1` doesn't have any advantage due to the small number of different values...

Can someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Your workmate is naive - at least the statement is, because it does ignore the real issue at hand.

Bit can be indexed, but the chance of an index with only 2 values to be useful is close to zero, which is why in most queries it will never be used. This is not intrinsic to bit but to the fact that it only has two values.

Interesting enough the same happens if the index is a smallint as it STILL only has two values. Same problem with not being selective enough and basically being most likely not used at all, especially not if any other index exists.

Now, logically the next step up from bit is not smallint but tinyint - half size.

Bits have advantages in storage. They CAN occupy only one bit... if you have multiple:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx

up to 8 are stored in one byte.